# Picking a new color for each contour component in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

Sometimes a specific contour level has several components. For instance:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
delta = 1./100  
x = np.arange(-2.0, 3.0, delta)  
y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)  
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)  
Z = Y * Y - X * X * X + X  
plt.figure()  
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, [0])
```

[image: Contour]

How do I color each component using its own color?

Comment: Those are the same color because they have the same value.

Comment: I know, the question is how to separate the colors. I assume matplotlib knows there are separate components, and I wish to use this information to color them differently.

Comment: Contour draws every thing at a given level as the same color via mapping the level value. You can grab the collection and start screwing with it, but that is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Yup, I looked in contour.py and saw that this is the way it works. I am putting something together now that seems to be not too terrible. will post it as a self-answer when I'm done (unless someone knows a better way).

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it! :) But it's hacky, so I'll leave my answer un-accepted until someone comes up with a better way to do it. Here is my solution (matplotlib 1.4.3).

As noted in the comments, what I asked is not something that **matplotlib.contour** knows how to do. But after investigating the code a little bit I came up with a solution that works and isn't too bad.

Behind the scenes, a class called **QuadContourSet** is used to store all the contour paths in "line collections", one line collection per level. The line collections are styled all together.

My idea was to subclass this class and replace the function **_get_allsegs_and_allkinds** with a function that separates the line collections to one line collection per *component*, instead of per-level. This is hacky so I named it **HackyContourSet** but it's good enough for my purposes.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import contour

class HackyContourSet(contour.QuadContourSet):
    def _get_allsegs_and_allkinds(self):
        allkinds = None
        allsegs = []
        for level in self.levels:
            nlist = self.Cntr.trace(level)
            nseg = len(nlist) // 2
            segs = nlist[:nseg]
            # Original code: allsegs.append(segs) - put all level segments in a
            # collection. New code: Put each segment in a separate collection.
            for seg in segs:
                allsegs.append([seg])
        # The following line is needed to make QuadContourSet think there are
        # more levels, so it would actually draw the additional collections.
        self.levels = [0] * len(allsegs)
        return allsegs, allkinds

####################

delta = 1./100
x = np.arange(-2.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = Y * Y - X * X * X + X

plt.figure()
plt.cla()
axes = plt.gca()
CS = HackyContourSet(axes, X, Y, Z, [0], colors=list('rb'))
```

[image]